# Magento 2: I need to show all products collection name in custom attribute dropdown in catalog products grid in admin

Tags: magento2

I need to show all products collection name in custom attribute dropdown in catalog products grid in admin.

[image]

I just want to show Products dropdown like colors dropdown.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you did anything?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you?

Comment: hi @Shomita, i have addded the answer, update me if you face any issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try Below code this will give you all the product names in dropdown as per your question.**

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Setup/InstallData.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    private $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'product_collection_names',
            [
                'group' => 'General',
                'type' => 'int',
                'label' => 'Product Names',
                'source' => \Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source\Options::class,
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'searchable' => false,
                'filterable' => false,
                'comparable' => false,
                'visible_on_front' => true,
                'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                'unique' => false,
                'apply_to' => 'simple,configurable,virtual,bundle,downloadable'
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/Config/Source/Options.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source;

class Options extends \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource
{
    public function __construct
    (
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollection
    ) 
    {
        $this->_productCollection = $productCollection->create();
        $this->_productCollection->addFieldToSelect('*');
    }

    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        $products = $this->_productCollection;

        foreach ($products as $product) 
        {
            $this->_options[] = ['label' => $product->getName(), 'value' => $product->getId()];
        }

        return $this->_options;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you should use the repository pattern to get the required data

```
<?php 

use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;

class Add<Your-Attribute-Name> implements DataPatchInterface
{
    /**
     * ModuleDataSetupInterface
     *
     * @var ModuleDataSetupInterface
     */
    private $moduleDataSetup;

    /**
     * EavSetupFactory
     *
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * constructor.
     *
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface  $moduleDataSetup
     * @param EavSetupFactory           $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
        EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function apply()
    {
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);

        $eavSetup->addAttribute('catalog_product', '<attribute_name>', [
            'group' => 'General',
            'type' => 'int',
            'label' => '<attribute_label>',
            'source' => \Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source\Options::class,
            'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'user_defined' => false,
            'searchable' => false,
            'filterable' => false,
            'comparable' => false,
            'visible_on_front' => true,
            'used_in_product_listing' => true,
            'unique' => false,
            'apply_to' => 'simple,configurable,virtual,bundle,downloadable'
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }
}

<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source;

use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;

class Options extends \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource
{

    /** @var ProductRepositoryInterface */
    protected $productRepository;

    /** @var SearchCriteriaBuilder */
    protected $searchCriteriaBuilder;

    public function __construct(
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder
    ) {
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
    }

    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        //->addFilter($fieldName, $fieldValue, $filterType) if you want to filter product on specific condition
        $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->create();
        $products = $this->productRepository->getList($searchCriteria)->getItems();

        foreach ($products as $product) 
        {
            $this->_options[] = ['label' => $product->getName(), 'value' => $product->getId()];
        }

        return $this->_options;
    }
}
```